# Styling entry-meta among others in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I edit the properties of wordpresses div's? e.g `entry-meta`? They're not located in the theme's CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is cascading, meaning you can add your own rules in a new file and they will override the existing ones. So create a new style sheet and link it into the HTML document after the existing stylesheets.

Comment: Changes should be added to the existing CSS file to limit extra (unnecessary) http calls.